# Cutting columns in many files - Bash - how do I save the results in different files?

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I'm writing a script that would allow me cut columns number 2, 4, 5... in many files.
I know that I have to use awk to print only required columns. But how do I save the results in different files? What do I write after > ?

Comment: Please let us know what you have attempted so far

Comment: @Julia: `awk` is one possibility, `cut` is another one. You could write a script which processes one file, and then use `find` or `xargs` to apply this script to each file individually. Only if you have a huge number of files to process, this approach will be too inefficient, but in this case, I would also recommend against `awk`, but use a single program in (say) Ruby, Perl or Python, to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2):

with gawk you can use `FILENAME` variable, and in your awk codes, redirect the required columns to `FILENAME"_new"` for example.

```
awk '{... ;print $2,$4,$5> FILENAME"_new"}' *.csv
```

You may want to add `close(FILENAME"_new")` if you have many files.